# Handlebars template tags in helpers string

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js

Is it possible to put handlebar template tag inside generated html string?

For example:

```
Ember.Handlebars.helper(...) {
  return new Handlebars.SafeString("<button {{action go}}></button>");
}
```

I know this doesn't work but can anyone suggest the right way? (if exists)
Html source of that is:

```
<button {{action go}}></button>
```

but it should be something like that:

```
<button data-ember-action="x"></button>
```

where x is some integer

Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can compile and call the template in runtime:

```
Ember.Handlebars.helper('trigger-action', function(options) {
  var compiledTemplate = Ember.Handlebars.compile('</h1><a href="#" {{action go}}>Click</a>');  
  return compiledTemplate(null, options);
});
```

Sample http://emberjs.jsbin.com/uhedazok/1/edit

Keep in mind that the template is always compiled, so you can have some performance problems.

Comment: What about multiple options? How to pass them?

Comment: nvm i figured it out. Thanks :)

Comment: is it possible to pass params to action name?